# Do browse served a cached file if its name or contents change?

Tags: caching, browser, browser-cache, expires-header

Two general questions I'm wondering about both in the case for a given file(.js, .css, etc.) where you've set an expires header and also when you have not:

1. Do browsers request a new file (NOT serving the cached one) only if the file **name** has changed? Browser's don't assess the file **contents** too, correct?
2. Do **ALL** browsers behave the same regarding question #1 or are there known to be differences between them, for example on mobile (iOS safari, etc.)?

thank you,
tim

Comment: The only way for the browser to check contents is for it to download a new copy of the file, therefore refreshing the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The browser can't check file contents unless it downloads the file. (The browser does not, for example, request a checksum). It usually delegates the task of content-checking (or timestamp-checking) to the server. The browser will send an if-modified-since header with a timestamp. The webserver will check to see if the file has changed, and if not, it will send a 304 not modified code.
2. All browsers follow this basic protocol. Servers may vary in how they decide if a file has changed.

Comment: -@user237815, thanks for your answer, one last question: how does setting or not the expires headers fit in with this to download or not decision tree?

Comment: Good question. I do not know about the interaction of the expires header and if-modified-since. The spec is here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21